# Animating plot with matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to animate a plot for this equation see below I'm trying to animate it for b  when 300>= b <= 486

```
clear all, clc,clf,tic
m=3.73;
a=480;
b=486;
r=1;
fs=44100;
x=linspace(0,2*pi,fs)';
y=m^3*cos(sqrt(a*r*x)).^(0.77)/r + m^3*cos(sqrt(b*r*x)).^(0.77)/r-20;
normalize_y=(y/max(abs(y))*0.8);
plot(x,y)
```

I'm using octave 3.8.1 which is a clone of matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be to use the handle of a plot and then only update the `'YData'`-property of a plot. That is especially useful for more complex plots where there are more than 1 line but you only want to change one line. Also Axis-labels are not overwritten then, which generally prevents alot of overhead.
In Matlabcode it could look like this:

```
% // Parameter and x-range
m=3.73;
a=480;
r=1;
fs=44100;
x=linspace(0,2*pi,fs)';
% // function to compute y for given x and parameter b
f = @(x, b) m^3*cos(sqrt(a*r*x)).^(0.77)/r + m^3*cos(sqrt(b*r*x)).^(0.77)/r-20;

% // first plot out of loop (to get plot handle)
figure;
b = 300;
y = f(x, b);
handle = plot(x, y);
xlabel('x') % // only set once
ylabel('y=f(x,b)') % // only set once
title(['b = ' num2str(b)]);
pause(0.1);

% // animate for b = 301 to 86
for b = 301:486 %// Change
    set(handle, 'YData', f(x, b)) % set new y-data in plot handle
    pause(0.1); %// update plot
    title(['b = ' num2str(b)]); %// update title
end
```

Comment: I tried running you code and I got 
error: octave_base_value::array_value(): wrong type argument 'complex matrix' in the line set(handle, 'YData', f(x, b)) % set new y-data in plot handle

Comment: @RickT okay that is unfortunate, in Matlab this code works well and produces the animated plot. It just throws this warning: ``Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored``, but i get the same warning when i run the other suggested solution to your problem.

Comment: I found a work around I can use set(handle, 'YData', real (f(x, b))) and this will work

Answer (score 1):

Put your plotting code in a `for` loop with `b` as the iterating variable, then place a `pause` for a small amount of time.  After, plot your graph, then use `drawnow` to refresh the plot.  In other words, try this code.  I've placed `%// Change` comments in your code where I have introduced new lines:

```
m=3.73;
a=480;
r=1;
fs=44100;
x=linspace(0,2*pi,fs)';
figure;
for b = 300 : 486 %// Change
    y=m^3*cos(sqrt(a*r*x)).^(0.77)/r + m^3*cos(sqrt(b*r*x)).^(0.77)/r-20;
    normalize_y=(y/max(abs(y))*0.8);
    pause(0.1); %// Change
    plot(x,y);
    title(['b = ' num2str(b)]); %// Change
    drawnow; %// Change
end
```

As a bonus, I've put what the current value of `b` is at each drawing of the plot.  BTW, I don't know why `normalize_y` is in your code when you aren't using it.  Do you mean to plot `normalize_y` instead of `y`?  Just an after thought.  Anyway, try that out and see how it looks.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This will work with octave 3.8.1

```
% // Parameter and x-range
m=3.73;
a=480;
r=1;
fs=44100;
x=linspace(0,2*pi,fs)';
% // function to compute y for given x and parameter b
f = @(x, b) m^3*cos(sqrt(a*r*x)).^(0.77)/r + m^3*cos(sqrt(b*r*x)).^(0.77)/r-20;

% // first plot out of loop (to get plot handle)
figure;
b = 300;
y = f(x, b);
handle = plot(x, y);
xlabel('x') % // only set once
ylabel('y=f(x,b)') % // only set once
title(['b = ' num2str(b)]);
pause(0.1);

% // animate for b = 301 to 86
for b = 301:486 %// Change
    %set(handle, 'YData', f(x, b)) % set new y-data in plot handle

    %To work with octave 3.8.1 use the line below
    set(handle, 'YData', real (f(x, b)))

    pause(0.1); %// update plot
    title(['b = ' num2str(b)]); %// update title
end
```